# Execute multiple scripts from one button

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have written several scripts that are executed by pressing a button (implemented with the insert drawing tool). I am wondering if there is a way I can assign a drop down to the button, in order to click it and then select which script I would like to run.

The situation is:

The button name will be Slope.
I would like to click on it and be able to choose 2:1,4:1 or 6:1. Or have the button execute a pop up menu with those options to execute the applicable script.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible to add a drop-down to an inserted image. The alternatives are to open an HTML dialog, a side-bar or a custom menu. For details, see the following official guides:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [Custom menus in Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

Comment: I will look into these some more. I have read into them some but am struggling to understand how to get it all to work as I don't have much programming experience. I am looking to click the button, have that open a pop up menu within the spreadsheet, the pop up menu would have two or three different check boxes and a different script would execute depending on which checkbox you clicked? Is this possible?

Comment: Personally I would recommend using a Custom menu for what you are describing. The use of top level, and sub menu choices sounds like it will do what you want.

Comment: @jnohl: Yes, it's possible, I think, but if you are just starting with Google Apps Script I think that you should try first the custom menus.

Comment: Ruben- I have made the custom menus but that is not really what I am looking for. This will be done many times repetitively so I don't want the user to have to go up into the menu's each time. I am looking for the button functionality, where the button is located somewhere on the sheet, when pressed, you are prompted for two options and a different script will execute based on which option you choose.

Comment: That's fine. By the way if you are looking for help on how to do that, please post a new question.

Comment: Ok. I will post another with the function portion of the script. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Rubén I now have a code that is working partially to operate a UI but can't get the last piece to function. I posted a new question "Checkbox UI with Multiple Options". Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Rubén I got it figured out and removed the post. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: It's worth to say that you can answer your own question. It's a way to document what you learned and shared it with others that could have the same question.